# OCMockito mocking calls with block

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmockito

I want to mock an object with the following message declaration:

`- (void)createWithCompletion:(void (^)(FuseResult *result, NSError *err)) completion;`

Is it possible to mock the block call this message has to handle?

I read the [ArgumentCaptorTest](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito/blob/master/Source/Tests/ArgumentCaptorTest.m) which has block but I wasn't sure if it's relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scroll down to the bottom of https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito and you'll see "Capturing arguments for further assertions". The second example shows how to use `MKTArgumentCaptor` to capture a block argument, then call it.

Here's an example:

```
MKTArgumentCaptor *argument = [[MKTArgumentCaptor alloc] init];
[verify(mockObject) createWithCompletion:[argument capture]];
void (^completion)(FuseResult *result, NSError *err) = [argument value];
completion(someResult, someErr);
```

This doesn't make `mockObject` call the block in any way. Instead, it captures the block passed to `mockObject`. The final step is to call the captured block with whatever arguments you want for your test.

Comment: I am kind of confused to what exactly that does. I want to specify *a priori* the behavior how the mock would call with a particular set of argument to this block when the message is being sent to the mock. (I want something akin to this `given([obj createWithCompletion:]) willReturn`). Is that what's possible there?

Comment: No. With the argument captor, a test grabs the block that was passed in, then calls whatever it wants to on the block. So basically, the "act" portion of the test has two steps.

Comment: Great, finding it pretty useful after trying it out.

Comment: Is it possible to verify if this calls gets called at all? Right now if it doesn't get called MKTCapturingMatcher would throw  NSException. Am I suppose to catch this?

Comment: You shouldn't have to deal with exceptions. Please file an issue at https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito

Comment: I submitted at https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito/issues/51. Thanks for the great framework.

Comment: @JonReid - Is there anything similar to the Kiwi's 'stub and do': `[[myObj stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) { ... }];`.  This was handy in Kiwi since you could replace a given method with your own implementation.

Comment: @Robert There is now.`willDo:`